# Set Angular2-DatePicker empty initially

Tags: angular, datepicker

I've applied the angula2-datetimepicker in my application by following this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datetimepicker).

I have to show empty datepicker initally. Following is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<angular2-date-picker [(ngModel)]="Model.SelectedDate" #SelectedDate="ngModel" name="SelectedDate" [settings]="datePickerSettings"></angular2-date-picker>
```

**Code:**

```
constructor() {
    DatePicker.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {
    this.settings = Object.assign(this.defaultSettings, this.settings);
    if (this.settings.defaultOpen) {
      this.popover = true;
    }
    this.date = new Date();
    };
}
datePickerSettings = {
  bigBanner: false,
  timePicker: false,
  format: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
  defaultOpen: false
}
```

It is showing the current date as a default but i do not want to show date in the datepicker.

[image]

Comment: Try Model.SelectedDate = null

Comment: @Chellappan already tried, not working

Comment: As per this package code, you can not set input as empty, because he is checking if you are setting any date or giving any date as input then set it else set the current date.

Comment: @FarhatZaman would you please send me the link to read it?

Comment: https://github.com/CuppaLabs/angular2-datetimepicker/tree/master/src/app/angular2-datetimepicker

Comment: @NimitJoshi for this purpose you can use angular material datePicker.
https://v5.material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: @FarhatZaman i want the datetimepicker..

Comment: @NimitJoshi then try this one https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker
here is a link of github and demo page
https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/

Answer (score 0):

Initialize [(ngModel)] value as type `any`.

**Eg**

**HTML**

```
<angular2-date-picker [(ngModel)]="selectedDate">
```

**TS**

```
selectedDate : any;
```

Comment: i have removed the format, but it showing the full date as 26-Dec-2018 11:50 AM

Answer (score 0):

better try to use mydatepicker here we have better options.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mydatepicker
for options attribute refer:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-datepicker

Comment: i've to use datetimepicker.

Comment: here you will get epoc time that you can use for getting time